# Select list and Button group alignment

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tiny issue in that my DropDownListFor control (Select) is not aligning with my button-group button.

The button is a pixel too big.

[image]

Here is a close up of the issue I am seeing. Note the mis-alignment.

[image]

```
<div class="input-group">
                        <select class="cmdDestination form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DestinationEntityId must be a number." data-val-required="A destination for the transaction is required" id="DestinationEntityId" name="DestinationEntityId" onchange="populateDefaults()"><option value="">Select payee</option>
<option value="201">Coles</option>
<option value="202">Company I work For</option>
<option value="205">paulo</option>
</select>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <a href="#new-payee" data-toggle="modal">
                                <span class="btnAddDestinationPayee glyphicon glyphicon-plus credit_colour" title="Add a new Payee"> </span>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

It seem the Select control is a pixel or two smaller than all my other controls. Is there a way to make these items align correctly?

Comment: I really don't understand your question, but just in case, that input in a circle has the EXACT width of all the drop-downs (I measured them with Photoshop). Then again, I don't understand your question so not sure if this is of help of not

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I've uploaded a zoomed in image to the question, showing the misalignment I am seeing. I am trying to get the heights to match. Strange thing: If I try it on a bootstrap code testing site - it seems fine. http://www.bootply.com/1F68PwJHvW - Aligns fine. But as you can see in my screenshot - it's not aligning on my site.